Translating place names to addresses or coordinates for use in QGIS
I'm currently working on creating some heatmaps of data that I downloaded from an online database. When I downloaded the data into an excel sheet, the database had automatically added a new field with longitude and latitude values to make it easier to map the data as points. This is great, however roughly half of the 5,500 or so points did not have an actual address (instead they had the name of a park or business, for example). Because of this, many of these points were placed in the same location by QGIS because it defaulted to the city name.
Is there any way in QGIS or Excel to make my life easier and translate these places back to addresses or coordinates in a batch instead of editing all 2,000+ one by one?

You'd need a business name to address lookup, like yellow pages (if that even still exists), attribute join the tables and then use geocoding to resolve addresses to locations https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GeoCoding/ - it won't solve all your problems but should get you closer than you are now.

MMQGIS plugin search 'Geocode Tools'  here https://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/ can batch geocode with different geocoders some require and api key.
